# Solr: storing index on a different server

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to run Solr on a server and store its index in a different location?

My use case would be: use an AWS EC2 as Solr server and a S3 as index storage (for persistence purpose)

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: I guess you intend to back up your index. You can do it via rsync, which is a file syncing software. Use Solr replication if you want a real-time option.

Comment: More precisely, I'd like to have the <dataDir> set to the an S3 bucket in order to avoid having persistent data on he EC2 instance. Is it feasible ?

Comment: I know I am not answering your question, but if your EC2 instance is S3-backed, your data *will* be in S3 anyway, so why worrying?

Comment: I am using an AWS Beanstalk (mainly for simplification purpose). It doesn't seem that the EC2 instance is backed-up in the S3. Is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AWS Beanstalk EC2 instance is backed by an EBS volume. However this volume is (by default) deleted each time the EC2 instance is terminated (manually or when a failure occured).

Solution : create an additonal EBS volume, attach it to the EC2 instance (using the AWS console) and mount it  and format it (using ssh). When done, Solr configuration files ($SOLR_HOME) and its dataDir (holding the indexes) will be stored on this EBS volume and persist when EC2 isntance is stopped.